# PHP Linking Database Generated Menu with the Correct Records

Tags: php, menu, navigation

I generated a navigation menu for each user stored in my database. Each link redirects the user to an external web page.

**Example of my menu:**

John 
     Personal Information 
     Account Information 
     Family Members 
Ann 
     Personal Information 
     Account Information 
     Family Members

```
<?php
foreach($users->results() as $user){
    echo
        '<li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Users">
                <span>' . $user->userName . '</span>
            </a>

            <div class="sidebar-submenu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="personalInfomation.php" title="Personal Information"><span>Personal Information</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="accountInformation.php" title="Account Information"><span>Account Information</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="familyMembers.php" title="Family Members"><span>Family Members</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </li>';
    } 
}
?>
```

As you can see I have 3 PHP files and their purpose is to display data back to the user. Since all sub-menu pages are identically generated, they will be displaying the SAME data back to the user.

So I was wondering if there is a way to I could tweak my code so when a user clicks John->Personal Information, only John's personal information will be displayed.

I thought about saving the user_id (PK) inside in the a tag's value attribute and somehow retrieving it...later on.

```
<li>
<a href="personalInfomation.php" title="Personal Information" value="' . $user->user_id .'">
    <span>Personal Information</span>
</a>
```

But it seems really inefficient and may be a big security flaw.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: why don't you store the personal information in the database along the username? so you could easily `select pinfo from tab where username = :user` and output it filtered by a parameter

Comment: `<li><a href="personalInfomation.php?user='.$user->userid.'" title="Personal Information"><span>Personal Information</span></a></li>';`  Then u can use the user id to get the user's info, or use the username to get details of the user, u just need to add query string on ur targeted link, then get the query string n perform query